# Changing font in console Vim

Tags: command-line, vim, fonts

I need to change the size of the font inside the terminal Vim (**not GUI Vim!**). I am working on Windows, what kind of command can I use (I'll map it to a key after that). I do not want to go and change the properties of the console window manually, I need a command that can quickly increment/decrement such values.

Edit after acceptance: I ended up going to gVim

Comment: You have to change your console font size if you're in a console. Please close your question.

Comment: Seems like this question is more suitable for SuperUser.

Comment: Why wouldn't you put it in https://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no command in Windows for switching console fonts.
The best you can do is write your own program which does that. Here's sample code that may help:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may turn to [Console Emulator](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) (I'm the author of ConEmu). One of its features - changing font size by hotkey or Ctrl+Wheel (by default). It works on any Windows starting from Windows 2000.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) on Windows; it's a lot friendlier than `cmd.exe`, and allows changing the font and font size as well as resizing the window and some other niceties.

Comment: Curious, did you try ConEmu?

Comment: no; i'm not sure ConEmu even existed when i still used windows